# Almost sure convergence and convergence in mean

Tags: probability, strong-convergence

I know that if $X_n\rightarrow Y$ almost surely, this does not necessarily imply that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}|X_n-Y|\rightarrow 0$ (this would require additional proof, using for example uniform integrability).
However, I am interested in a weaker statement:
$$\lim\mathbb{E}X_n-\mathbb{E}Y\rightarrow 0.$$
Can this property be deduced from almost surely convergence?

Comment: $X_n=n\chi_{(0,\frac  1 n)}, Y=0$.

Comment: Thank you. To make sure, the mean in your example diverges right?

Comment: A follow-up question. If I can show that $\lim\mathbb{E}X_n<\infty$, will this be enough for almost surely convergence to imply the convergence in the question?

Comment: $EX_n=1$ for all $n$ in my example.